# Android adapter.add() crashing my application

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

in android application, i'm filling my spinner with some data coming from EditText object.
And when i'm trying  to add it with adapter.add(somestring) method it crashes, so i need help.
...here's the code

```
public class OptionsMenu extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

    Spinner users;
    EditText input;
    Button add,remove;

    public static String filename = "savedData";
    SharedPreferences sharedData;
    String stringUsers;

   ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;

   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.options_menu);

        Create();
        sharedData = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);    
   }

private void Create() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    users = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_op_users);
    input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tb_op_inputUsers);
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_op_add);
    remove = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_op_remove);

    add.setOnClickListener(this);
    remove.setOnClickListener(this);

    //------------ADAPTER-----------------  
    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.users,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    users.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.bt_op_add:
            if (!input.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                CharSequence inputData = input.getText().toString();
                adapter.add(inputData);

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                users.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
            input.setText("");
            users.setSelection(Adapter.NO_SELECTION);
            break;
        case R.id.bt_op_remove:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Answer (score 2):

Not very sure why you are getting the error but your `if` condition is wrong.

Change the following line:

```
if (input.getText().toString() != "")
```

to

```
if (!input.getText().toString().equals(""))
```

You don't compare `strings` using a `=` sign.

**EDIT**

Maybe you could first get the array from the resource file and create a local version of it:

```
String[] usersList=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.users);

adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, usersList)
```

and use this `usersList` as the list of data for your `adapter`.

Comment: there are some errors when i implement usersList, but is there a way to totally bypass whole array from resource thing...becouse i will eventually all my spinner items save in an external storage...

Answer (score 1):

You created the adapter using `createFromResource()` and provided it with the data from your resource. If you do it this way the list is fixed and you cannot add to or remove elements from it. This is why it crashed when you try to call `adapter.add()`.

If you want to have the spinner contain dynamic data, then you'll have to add all the elements to it using `add()` and not create it from a resource.

**EDIT: Add code example**

in onCreate() we create and initialize the spinner adapter

```
List<String> items = ... // These are your items you get from a resource or read
                         //  from a file or whatever
// Create the adapter, initializing it with the list of items, attach to spinner
adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
for (String item : items) {
    adapter.add(item);
}
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
users.setAdapter(adapter);
```

in onClick(), to add an item to the spinner:

```
case R.id.bt_op_add:
    if (!input.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        CharSequence inputData = input.getText().toString();
        adapter.add(inputData);
        // You shouldn't need to reset the adapter on the spinner, nor call
        //  notifyDataSetChanged() here
    }
    input.setText("");
    users.setSelection(Adapter.NO_SELECTION);
    break;
```

Comment: I edited my answer to add some code for you. I didn't run it through a compiler so please forgive me if i missed a semicolon or a closing parenthesis. Hopefully you get the idea.